# Yii Rights module error after converting to postgres

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, yii, rights

I have changed my applicaiton database from mysql  to postgres since this the rights module is giving exception:

```
`CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 
 ERROR: relation "authitem" does not exist
LINE 2: FROM AuthItem t1
^. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT
name,t1.type,description,t1.bizrule,t1.data,weight
FROM AuthItem t1
LEFT JOIN Rights t2 ON name=itemname
ORDER BY t1.type DESC, weight ASC `
```

I have reviewed the tables names and it's exactly the same 'case senstive'.

Answer (score 1):

If the table name in the database is `AuthItem` not `authitem` the query should be:

```
FROM "AuthItem" t1
```

Note the double quotes.

It looks like whatever you're using created the table as `CREATE TABLE "AuthItem"` but then queries it as `SELECT ... FROM AuthItem`. These are different things. Yes, that's confusing, but that's what the SQL standard says - case is *folded* on unquoted identifiers, and *preserved* on quoted identifiers.